# Wrap content based on window.innerHeight in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My website is very text-heavy, and I want to break it into pieces automatically based on the content height, like google docs or word does.

So I figured I'd use `window.innerHeight` to get the full height, and do something like:

```
$("content").ready(function(){
 from(window.innerHeight == 1,window.innerHeight == 70%){
     $(this).wrapInner('<div class="wrapper"> </div>').append('<div class="endpage"></div>')
 }
 from($(".endpage").innerHeight, $(".endpage").innerHeight + 70%){
     $(this).wrapInner('<div class="wrapper"> </div>').append('<div class="endpage"></div>')
 }})
```

Where the .wrapper div needs to wrap the elements that fill 70% of the screen like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   //content filling 70% of the screen height
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   //content filling 70% of the screen height
</div>
```

But of course, it doesn't work.

How would I do this?

**EDIT:**
As requested, here is a snippet:

```js
$("content").ready(function() {
  from(window.innerHeight == 1, window.innerHeight == 70 % ) {
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="wrapper"> </div>').append('<div class="endpage"></div>')
  }
  from($(".endpage").innerHeight, $(".endpage").innerHeight + 70 % ) {
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="wrapper"> </div>').append('<div class="endpage"></div>')
  }
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400i,700,700i");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,400i,700,700i");
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
th,
label {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  color: #0a0a0a;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

p,
td {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

p+p {
  text-indent: 2em;
}

ol,
ul {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 0em 1em;
  margin: 1em 0em;
}

ul ul,
ol ol {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <h1>lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed dui vel erat ornare tristique. Nulla tristique rutrum auctor. Etiam sed diam quam. Mauris suscipit tortor ut felis pharetra, eget semper lorem suscipit. Pellentesque sit amet mollis nulla.
    Vivamus at est congue, commodo ex id, aliquet dolor. Integer lobortis efficitur velit. Nam vehicula mattis lectus, at malesuada mauris convallis elementum.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed dui vel erat ornare tristique. Nulla tristique rutrum auctor. Etiam sed diam quam. Mauris suscipit tortor ut felis pharetra, eget semper lorem suscipit. Pellentesque sit amet mollis nulla.
      Vivamus at est congue, commodo ex id, aliquet dolor. Integer lobortis efficitur velit. Nam vehicula mattis lectus, at malesuada mauris convallis elementum.</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed dui vel erat ornare tristique. Nulla tristique rutrum auctor. Etiam sed diam quam. Mauris suscipit tortor ut felis pharetra, eget semper lorem suscipit. Pellentesque sit amet mollis
        nulla. Vivamus at est congue, commodo ex id, aliquet dolor. Integer lobortis efficitur velit. Nam vehicula mattis lectus, at malesuada mauris convallis elementum.</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed dui vel erat ornare tristique. Nulla tristique rutrum auctor. Etiam sed diam quam. Mauris suscipit tortor ut felis pharetra, eget semper lorem suscipit. Pellentesque sit amet mollis nulla.
      Vivamus at est congue, commodo ex id, aliquet dolor. Integer lobortis efficitur velit. Nam vehicula mattis lectus, at malesuada mauris convallis elementum.</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed dui vel erat ornare tristique. Nulla tristique rutrum auctor. Etiam sed diam quam. Mauris suscipit tortor ut felis pharetra, eget semper lorem suscipit. Pellentesque sit amet mollis
        nulla. Vivamus at est congue, commodo ex id, aliquet dolor. Integer lobortis efficitur velit. Nam vehicula mattis lectus, at malesuada mauris convallis elementum.</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed dui vel erat ornare tristique. Nulla tristique rutrum auctor. Etiam sed diam quam. Mauris suscipit tortor ut felis pharetra, eget semper lorem suscipit. Pellentesque sit amet mollis nulla.
      Vivamus at est congue, commodo ex id, aliquet dolor. Integer lobortis efficitur velit. Nam vehicula mattis lectus, at malesuada mauris convallis elementum.</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed dui vel erat ornare tristique. Nulla tristique rutrum auctor. Etiam sed diam quam. Mauris suscipit tortor ut felis pharetra, eget semper lorem suscipit. Pellentesque sit amet mollis
        nulla. Vivamus at est congue, commodo ex id, aliquet dolor. Integer lobortis efficitur velit. Nam vehicula mattis lectus, at malesuada mauris convallis elementum.</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Replace the double quotes with singles: `'<div class="wrapper"> </div>'` first. Also, Can you create a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for this?

Comment: @MoshFeu how can I create a working snippet of the problem I can't get to work?

Comment: By working snippet I mean a snippet that reproduce the problem. If I want to debug it to help you I have to create a similar page by myself. If you will help us, it will easy for us to help you :)

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What are you expecting to happen that doesn't happen? Or, what happens that you don't expect to happen?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I need it to wrap the elements that fill 70% of the screen in the .wrapper div

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that detail. See [ask] for more information on what is expected in a question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define your sections individually:

```
var wph = $(".wrapper").height(); //this could be window.innerHeight
if( wph > 50 ){
$(".wrapper").wrapInner("<div class='pager'></div>");
}
```

Then you could define a value using str.length:

```
$(".wrapper").text().length;
```

This could help to layout your content.